# How to select/unselet checkboxes dynamically in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Iam trying to select/unselect the checkboxes based on the condition, if tag.id is equal to taged.id then make it check otherwise not. I am doing an update in the post so I need to know which tag is checked by the user initially.

Here is my code:-


TAG

```
  <div className="col-sm-10">
    <div className="checkbox">
      {tate.tags.map(
        (tag) =>
         { hiding.hide &&
            <label key={taged.id}>
              <input
                name="tag[]"
                value={tag.id}
                onChange={handlecheck}
                type="checkbox"
                (form.tags.map(taged => {
                checked={tag.id === taged.id ? true : false}
              />})}
              namnemnma {tag.Tag_name}
            </label>
          }
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code base.

Comment: `checked={tag.id === taged.id } ` this is enough